# Iframe not loading page with the same domain name

Tags: internet-explorer, iframe

I have added an iframe in my html code.

Say my domain is http://localhost/mySite. Now i want to load a page in iframe which is same domain. i.e. http://localhost/mySite/MyOrders this works in chrome but in IE it is not loading in iframe i.e. I am getting blank in iframe. However if i load any other site like bing.com it loads. Can anyone please give me any suggestion on this.

What I have tried:

I have tried adding same origin in web.config like this

```
<httpProtocol>
    <customHeaders>
      <add name="X-Frame-Options" value="SAMEORIGIN" />
    </customHeaders>
    </httpProtocol>
```

added within system.web

Also i tried to add the below in

`<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE11" />
<meta http-equiv="X-Frame-Options" content="SAMEORIGIN">`

Answer (score 0):

I tried to test the issue on my side by configuring the files in a similar way.

On my side, it worked fine.

[image]

It can be settings related issue on the IE browser.

If possible for you then you can try to reset the IE browser to see whether it helps to fix this issue.

> Go to Tools-> Internet Options-> Advanced tab-> Reset

Let us know about your test results.